# bpy module still not found after building blender as a python module on Linux

Tags: linux, python, blender

I have been trying to build blender as a python module on my Linux (Debian GNU/Linux 9.9) virtual machine, and I have been having a lot of trouble.

I have followed this instructions:

https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126959/how-to-build-blender-as-python-module

and have tried with different versions of Blender (2.81 and 2.79) and with different variations in step 2 of installing the dependencies such as install_deps.sh --skip-python --skip-numpy.

In step 3 (Compiling blender with CMake) I run the below command in cd ~/blender-git/blender instead of just make. These parameters(except for the `-D WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=OFF` `-D WITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON` which I added), is what the output told be to do after running  install_deps.sh .

```
  sudo make bpy -j2 BUILD_CMAKE_ARGS="-U *SNDFILE* -U *PYTHON* -U *BOOST* -U *Boost* -U *OPENCOLORIO* -U *OPENEXR* -U *OPENIMAGEIO* -U *LLVM* -U *CYCLES* -U *OPENSUBDIV* -U *OPENVDB* -U *COLLADA* -U *FFMPEG* -U *ALEMBIC* -D WITH_CODEC_SNDFILE=ON -D PYTHON_VERSION=3.5 -D WITH_OPENCOLORIO=ON -D OPENCOLORIO_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/ocio -D WITH_OPENIMAGEIO=ON -D OPENIMAGEIO_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/oiio -D WITH_CYCLES_OSL=ON -D WITH_LLVM=ON -D LLVM_VERSION=3.4 -D WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=OFF -D WITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON -D OSL_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/osl -D LLVM_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/llvm -D LLVM_STATIC=ON -D WITH_OPENSUBDIV=ON -D OPENSUBDIV_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/osd -D WITH_OPENVDB=ON -D WITH_OPENVDB_BLOSC=ON -D WITH_ALEMBIC=ON -D ALEMBIC_ROOT_DIR=/opt/lib/alembic -D WITH_CODEC_FFMPEG=ON -D FFMPEG_LIBRARIES='avformat;avcodec;avutil;avdevice;swscale;swresample;lzma;rt;theora;theoradec;theoraenc;vorbis;vorbisenc;vorbisfile;ogg;x264'"
```

After this step, I get a message that blender was successfully built, but then after trying to import bpy, after typing python3 or python in the Linux command like I get this error:

```
>>> import bpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/username/blender-git/build_linux_bpy/bin/2.79/scripts/modules/bpy/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from _bpy import types, props, app, data, context
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bpy'
```

This is after adding this to my Pythonpath:

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/username/blender-git/build_linux_bpy/bin/2.79/scripts/modules:/home/username/blender-git/build_linux_bpy/bin/2.79/scripts/modules/bpy

I take the error above to mean that it is trying to run it as an internal blender C module according to this post .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187025/blender-python-bpy-init-py-apparently-importing-from-a-non-existent-mod

My question is what am I missing here to make this work? Is there a parameter that I am missing when running sudo make bpy? Do I need to do something different in the Pythonpath? Do I need to have a specific version of python in order for this to work? (I have 2.7 and 3.7 that came from the anaconda package).

About two years ago I was able to successfully build blender 2.78 as a python module in my windows machine and use it directly from my python interpreter in eclipse. I remember the process being tedious as well, but this time I feel like I have exhausted all the answers from the internet.

If anyone has successfully build blender as a python module on linux, and has ran into similar issues as mine and could point me to what I am doing wrong I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Seems like the Blender scripts directory could be in the wrong place. Maybe take a snapshot of your configuration. As is it's kind of hard to tell. [Possibly related](https://github.com/TylerGubala/blenderpy/wiki/Caveat---Usage-with-multiprocessing)

Comment: Also you should not be required to mangle your sys.path in that way. You have to go into your build directory and copy the bpy.so file as well as all constituent libraries into your site-packages. Then place your scrips directory sibling to your Python executable. You cannot expect to change the sys.path and just have it work as the _bpy module is instantiated in the c code just prior to the addons module et al.